# Which OSI-Layer does Ethernet belong to?

Tags: ethernet

Just wondering.

Comment: Why is this being voted off-topic?   A question about networking sure seems like it belongs on serverfault.

Comment: I Agree with Zoredache.  Should stay open.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ethernet is a [collection of specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.3) for layers 1 (PHY) and 2 (DLL).

Answer (score 1):

Layer 2.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet works at layer two and defines CSMA/CD.